# Is there a way to force a specific file to exist in RAM only?

Tags: performance, battery, disk, ssd

I like [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/optimize-ubuntu-for-ssd/1675#1675) of mounting a tmpfs at `/var/log` in order to reduce disk writes.

Is there any way to do something similar for just a single file such as `~/.xsession-errors`?

---

My incentive for asking comes from [PowerTOP](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/),

```
The program 'gnome-do' is writing to file '.xsession-errors' on /dev/sdb2.
This prevents the disk from going to powersave mode.
```

but one could also conceivably want to do this in order to speed up an IO-intensive program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way you can force a single file not to be written to disk.  Writes to a file are passed down to the filesystem code: if the filesystem is backed by memory (e.g., `tmpfs`) then data is written to a (virtual) memory location; if the filesystem is backed by a block device (e.g., ext3/4) then data is written to the block device.

You can, however, symlink a specific file to a location in a `tmpfs` filesystem; this will work as long as: (1) the destination of the symlink exists, and (2) the link is not removed and the file re-created in the original (disk-based) filesystem.

Concerning `~/.xession-errors`, there is some special treatment in `/etc/X11/Xsession` (lines 63--72 as of `x11-common` version 1:7.5+5ubuntu1): *if `~/.xsession-errors` is already a symlink,* then a temporary file (in directory `$TMPDIR` or `/tmp`) is used instead.  So, if your `/tmp`or `$TMPDIR` filesystem is mounted from RAM, you're done.