# Best FS for SSD as of 10.10

Tags: 10.10, filesystem, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

Given what I think is a common scenario:

- SSD used as boot disk
- Conventional HD(s) for bulk storage
- Ubuntu 10.10

What's the best stable filesystem to use on the SSD? I'm ruling out NilFS and BTRFS because they are not stable as of 10.10.

I'm expecting to either put /home on the raid or at least back it up regularly, so the reliability difference between ext 2 and ext 3 doesn't seem like it should be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

While btrfs does have an optimized SSD, it is not recommended at this time.

After doing some research, I found a mixed bag of opinions ranging from ext4 without journaling over ext2.

Under ServerFault (another StackExchange site), it was deduced that SSD should be treated like a regular HD.  Choose the file system that meets the type of file needs.

Here is a point of reference: [stackexchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/110127/which-filesystem-is-best-for-centos-5-on-ssd)