# How well are SSDs supported?

Tags: ssd, trim

I'm planning to buy an SSD (Corsair Force Series 60GB) but haven't found any reassurance that it is "safe" to install Ubuntu 11.04 on without commands or "hacks". I want to install Ubuntu on an SSD and don't want to care about writing commands after the installation to fix TRIM support.

My question is: Can I install Ubuntu 11.04+ on an SSD just like I do on an HDD and not have problems with TRIM and performance? Or does Ubuntu not support TRIM without technical configuration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enabling TRIM support does help maintain the highest performance of an SSD over time.  Enabling it is fairly simple, see this guide:

- [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim) ([old link](https://sites.google.com/site/lightrush/random-1/howtoconfigureext4toenabletrimforssdsonubuntu), for reference: )
- [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

You'll be happy with Ubuntu on an SSD -- it's quite snappy and works very well.

Comment: Why isn't it enabled on by default when an SSD is detected?

Comment: SATA TRIM _can't be queued_.  It can also take some time to process, and/or leave the drive "busy" (slower) for a time afterwards.  Guess what, it turns out invoking it after every single delete is not _automatically_ a good idea.  Just going from the specification, If you want an OS to "support" such a unique command