# Are configurations still needed for SSD drives in 12.04+

Tags: 12.04, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well are SSDs supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52258/how-well-are-ssds-supported)

I will be getting an SSD drive soon, but since 12.04 received many many changes in regards to everything, I was wondering if there is still a need to do several configuration changes to several files, for example, editing the `fstab` file to enhance the SSD performance and other changes.

Is this still needed to make an SSD's performance better? What changes are already incorporated into 12.04 that will make SSD performance better by default. What changes are still needed to modify?

Comment: @JorgeCastro - Are the options mentioned in that question still needed as of 12.04. For example Trim, noatime and any other options mentioned in there. My worry is, I put some money into the SDD (First SDD of my own) and what to make sure how to take care of it wisely. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, those are up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a SSD drive for half an year now (OCZ Vertex II) and didn't configurated it in any way. It runs just like a charm. I was interested in this topic too and so i did a research back then. The conclusion was:

1. What ever you do to speed up your SSD, you can't make it *noticeable* faster.
2. All these warnings on bad settings wearing out you SSD are negligible on newer SSD's and Operating Systems. More on SSD myths (especially on their endurance) [here](http://www.storagesearch.com/ssdmyths-endurance.html).

So, if you still have the feeling like somethings wrong with you SSD, use **palimpsest disk utiliy**. It can check your Harddrive for errors and measures it's speed.

Comment: Hi Serve, thanks for the answer. Can you please explain better your 2nd point.

Comment: Hey @LuisAlvarado. I updated the answer.