# Why is my Intel SSD 520 so slow?

Tags: 12.04, performance, intel, ssd

I'm running a fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with ext4 on a SSD 520 by Intel. My mainboard is an ASUS Crosshair (latest BIOS 1207) with a Sil 3132 SATA Controller which claims to support SATAII. I have TRIM enabled. But my results are pretty bad in comparison to what could be expected:

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   2510 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1255.51 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 376 MB in  3.00 seconds = 125.21 MB/sec
```

Is my mainboard bottlenecking it? Here are some info about the SSD in use:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       INTEL SSDSC2CW120A3                   
    Serial Number:      CVCV227301JE120BGN  
    Firmware Revision:  400i    
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0110) 
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  234441648
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  234441648
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      114473 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      120034 MBytes (120 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 1
    Advanced power management level: 254
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
            Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    unknown 76[14]
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 1 block)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    4min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5001517bb29a74d4
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 001517
    Unique ID   : bb29a74d4
Checksum: correct
```

Comment: "Sil 3132 SATA Controller" <-- Is this the only controller on the mainboard? This controller is known to be slow. You should have another controller too, I guess?

Comment: Oh and please link to the exact mainboard you have there, as there appear to be *many* Asus Crosshair boards (it's a whole family).

Comment: I am not completely sure about my mainboard, but it should be the first of its family: http://www.asus.com/ROG/CROSSHAIR/

After a closer look, I can confirm that besides the above mentioned RAID Controller I have 3 MCP55 SATA Controller onboard.

Comment: Then it does have two storage controllers: "NVIDIA nForce 590 SLI MCP" and "Silicon Image® 3132 SATA controller" as per the [specifications](http://www.asus.com/ROG/CROSSHAIR/#specifications).

Comment: Is this NVIDIA nForce 590 SLI MCP true SATAII as advertised by ASUS and even discribed on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NForce_500#nForce_590_SLI_MCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to the SSD, I also have an Intel 520 Series SSD Drive. Mine is the 120GB one. I ran the test as you mentioned and this is the result:

[image]

Although this is a test using 13.04, 2 weeks ago I was using it on 12.04 and it gave almost the same result (About ~40 MB less on the buffered disk reads but still high enough)

The only thing left here would be the motherboard. In my case I have the Intel DZ68DB with the latest firmware update. If I were to help in any way, I would first recommend:

- Updating the firmware of the motherboard from [here](http://www.asus.com/ROG/CROSSHAIR/#support_Download_8) in case you have not done so yet.
- Make sure to read [How well are SSDs supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52258/how-well-are-ssds-supported)
- Be sure to also read [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

Comment: At the end it was my motherboard's SATA Chip which is too slow. I bought myself a ASUS U3S6 PCI Card to bypass the issue for a while instead of buying a new motherboard, cpu and RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Speed test with hdparm (get/set ATA/SATA drive parameters under Linux)

```
# hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
```

Output:

```
/dev/sda:
Timing cached reads: 4476 MB in 1.99 seconds = 2244.15 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 714 MB in 3.00 seconds = 237.77 MB/sec
```

Disk I/O test

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync
```

Output:

```
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.69718 s, 229 MB/s
```

This is an intel 520 ssd 180 gb on dell 1121 http://namhuy.net/1541/intel-520-ssd-180gb-dell-1121-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

Random write performance for SSD hugely depends on write-caching inside device.

Check performance with two different options:

```
hdparm -W 0 /dev/sdX  # disable write cache
hdparm -W 1 /dev/sdX  # enable write cache
```