# Optimize Ubuntu install on USB-drive for longer life

Tags: usb-drive

I've got an Ubuntu installed on an USB-drive for portable use. It's a regular install and not a live USB. Needless to say, it's a Flash-based storage and only 16 GB. What can I do to extend its life?

N.B. Currently my main PC is missing a HDD so the USB-drive is in regular use. I'm afraid that I've already shaved off quite a bit of its life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the life of SSD is more affected by writes (than by readers) I would recommend two things:

1) Do not use a swap partition,

2) Edit the fstab to ad noatime for the mounted partitions:
`gksu gedit /etc/fstab`

It should looks like this:
`UUID=something / ext4 errors=remount-ro,noatime 0 1`

Also you may like to check this: [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/optimizing-the-os-for-ssds)

Comment: What exactly does `noatime` do? Forgive me if it's already mentioned in the link, but this is before reading it. Swap isn't used much (or at all), as far as I can tell, so I'd prefer to keep it in case of emergency need.

Comment: This options tells to system not to write the information of when the file or folder was accessed. Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab#Common_options_to_all_filesystems

Answer (score 4):

### ToRam

Probably the easiest way to prolong the USB stick life is to use the "toram" feature of a Live Environment boot.

This will boot the entire live CD/USB into RAM and therefore reduce/eliminate further USB disk accesses.

**to-do** - press F6 using the boot sequence and add `toram` to the boot string before the end `--` i.e. `.... toram --`

edit - not at my ubuntu - possibly `TORAM=yes` - I'll check later.

Comment: Since it's being used in place of a HDD, it's not a live installation (I would've mentioned if it was).

Comment: ok - its a full install - not a persistent install?  Worth adding that into your question to clarify.

Comment: Useful tip. Could you please clarify, as currently the answer is a bit vague?