# Save changes to filesystem in RAM, save to HDD on shutdown

Tags: tmpfs

This question is in continuation to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/59556/814). I download a lot of small files (a few MBs) which I delete after being done with them. So can I make it that all changes to be saved to my filesystem be made in the RAM if it's under certain size? For example, if I set the limit to 128 MB, all files under that size will be saved to the RAM, and only saved to the HDD before shutdown.

Comment: If those small files are thrown away after use, you can use a ramdisk as well. For example, my `/tmp` is mounted `tmpfs` (which resides in the RAM). If I need to peek into the source of a package, I `apt-get source` it in `/tmp`. When done, I remove it if I think about it.

Comment: My understanding is that tmpfs uses swap for storage, while ramfs uses RAM - see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, the dangers of writing to an SSD drive may be greatly [exaggerated](http://www.storagesearch.com/ssdmyths-endurance.html) - unless you're planning to prolong its life beyond year 2100 :)

Secondly, keeping the data in RAM and then writing it to the disk later in one go is basically what Linux filesystem does anyway - though the emphasis is on preserving the data, not minimizing the number of writes.

Thirdly, you can create a [ramdisk](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html) and save your temporary data there. Then I imagine you could have some script which rsync's the contents of the ramdrive with a folder on the disk. Then you can either invoke it manually (Big Save Button on your desktop) or add it to shutdown scripts. The whole thing would be pretty unreliable though.

I mean - moving swap and logs off an SSD is one thing, but, say, not saving a document I'm working on to minimize the number of writes may be a bit extreme :)

Comment: It's a *16* GB USB, even if exaggerated, at the rate I download and delete data, I'd say it'd hardly live two years.