# Can I install Ubuntu fully on usb thumb drive? NOT LIVE USB

Tags: system-installation

Can I install Ubuntu on usb during installation by setecting "something else"? And is it safe for my usb somebody said it destroys your usb after a while?

Comment: I have a 32GB usb

Comment: You can. I've done that. But it's painfully slow

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions, both duplicates.  How to install to a USB, as mentioned in the comments is a duplicate, and then how to extend the live of the USB in [Optimize Ubuntu install on USB-drive for longer life](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59556/optimize-ubuntu-install-on-usb-drive-for-longer-life)  which contains a link to further optimizations for SSDs in [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds) .  The easiest way to extend the life of USB installation is to run from the guest session, which is based in ram, minimizing the USB writes to cache (browser cache etc.).