# Ubuntu 11.10 on modern SSD

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, backup, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

There is already quite a lot of questions regarding SSD disks with Ubuntu.

But the technology moves forward. Are there any new things I need to know moving to SSD?

I'm planning to buy a fast 120GB SSD for my laptop and put the default installation there. `ext4` will be a good choice?

Then what? Do I still need any optimizations?

The performance will be already better than on regular HDD, so I guess my primary goal is optimizing for lifetime.