# SSD Tweaks for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dell, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

I need to tweak my Dell XPS 13z SSD for maximum performance and life cycle than I read the solutions explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86433/ubuntu-11-10-on-modern-ssd), but it is for 11.10 and my fstab is different.

For now my **fstab** is looks like this:

```
    proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=abf5ce9e-bdb7-4b2f-a7bd-bbd9efa72a98 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=491427b2-7482-4483-b6eb-7c564b991aff /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=7551000d-e708-4e0f-9fd2-9f93119f63fb none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
tmpfs     /tmp         tmpfs      mode=1777
```

And my **rc.local** is looks like this:

```
echo noop > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch

exit 0
```

Do you have any suggestions, what should I do?

Regards

Comment: "maximum performance and life cycle" those 2 things wont be maxed at even rates

Comment: Consider just not worrying about it. I'm using 2 SSDs and see a massive performance increase with no tweaks. The life cycle concerns have been debunked as well. Also, try editing your fstab to mount by label instead of UUID if you are seeing duplicate entries in Nautilus, it's a known bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are lots of tips out there for tweaking your SSD in Linux and
>   lots of anecdotal reports on what works and what doesn’t.  Below are things that can be done to improve performance.
>
> - Prominent Tweaks
> - Eschewing Access Times
> - Enabling TRIM
> - Tmpfs
> - Switching IO Schedulers

These are some things that you can try.  For complete explanation on how to use the above mentioned steps, Have a look at [How to Tweak Your SSD in Ubuntu for Better Performance](http://www.howtogeek.com/62761/how-to-tweak-your-ssd-in-ubuntu-for-better-performance/) and [How to tweak and optimize SSD for Ubuntu, Linux Mint](http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html)

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/62761/how-to-tweak-your-ssd-in-ubuntu-for-better-performance/

http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86433/ubuntu-11-10-on-modern-ssd) you are referring to is totally valid for 12.04 as well. However:

Your `fstab` looks different because partitions are specified using UUID's, rather than device labels as it is done in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/86474/2639).
[Google for "fstab uuid vs label"](https://www.google.com/search?q=fstab%20uuid%20vs%20label), and you'll see there is no real technical difference.

`/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` can accept only *one* value, but are setting scheduler to *noop* and then to *deadline*. Remove this line, it's not needed:

```
echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second line countermands your first line, changing the scheduler from noop to deadline.  Don't do that.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, right?

Comment: @TomBrossman, no?

Comment: Had to read it again, sorry. D'oh!