# SSD tweaks under 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, ssd

I'm going to install 13.04 on my home microserver, an HP N54L, specifically on a Kingston SSD. I'm wondering what tweaks are still worth making to extend the life of the SSD? I know that previously it was important to make a number of changes so that the OS is gentler on the drive.

Many thanks,
Hermonski

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150260/ssd-tweaks-for-ubuntu-12-04/150262#150262), see it might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Enable TRIM

TRIM (Trim command let an OS know which SSD blocks are not being used and can be cleared)

Back up fstab first in case something wrong happen.

```
# cp /etc/fstab ~/fstab.bk
```

Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add discard to your ssd drives or partitions, after ext4

```
UUID=bef10b86-494d-41c6-aa46-af72cfba90fd / ext4 discard,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add noatime,nodiratime to your ssd drives or partitions, after ext4

```
UUID=bef10b86-494d-41c6-aa46-af72cfba90fd / ext4 discard,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Disable hibernation

```
# nano /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

Look for

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

Change from “yes” to “no”, there are two, one for hibernation, and another one for suspend. If you have to disable them both, make sure to replace them both from yes to no.

```
<allow_active>no</allow_active>
```

Tmpfs

Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the line to the end of fstab file

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

If logs aren’t important for you (laptop or desktop), you can also mount /var/log to

```
tmpfs. Add the line to the end of fstab file
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=0755 0 0
```

From [How to tweak and optimize SSD for Ubuntu, Linux Mint](http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html)