# configuration for Samsung SSD 830

Tags: filesystem, ssd

I would like to know what would be the best filesystem configuration for a [Samsung SSD 830](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-7PC256D/AM) of a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install on my laptop (Asus U33JC). I've seen people suggesting a RAID configuration, but I have no idea where to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ext4` filesystem with `discard` mount option.

RAID is designed for multiple disks (be it HDDs or SSDs) and is used on servers.

See also:

- [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got it under default options in Ubuntu 12.04, but I am not sure if that includes the `discard` option. What would the `discard` option do?

Comment: this enables the trim function of the SSD. THe blocks on the ssd will be freed up when a file is deleted. This way you gain performance, but introduces a little extra wear to the ssd.

Answer (score 1):

To enable discard you should alter the /etc/fstab file. Mine looks like this after a clean install using two SSDs:

```
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=bd379bf3-bb3a-4c0e-a7e0-c6545903eb26 /               ext4    noatime,discard 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=3AE5-1A3B  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /data/large was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=69c10986-d12f-47d1-a90d-8c8b07909b4b /data/large     ext4    noatime,discard        0       2
# /data/medium was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=e9c90115-6530-4866-b43c-8084d87769e1 /data/medium    ext4    noatime,discard        0       2
# /data/small was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=e22f25a0-b8de-48dd-8799-b525f2afadff /data/small     ext4    noatime,discard        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8e2e8638-2098-4282-9a33-9d32db0932b7 /home           ext4    noatime,discard        0       2
```

The noatime means it won't update the "last access time" when you open the files, saving a few extra writes.