# What filesystem should I use for a Seagate Momentus XT Hybrid ST750LX003?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, ssd, hybrid

I am considering upgrading my regular HDD hard drive on my laptop by the SSD/HDD Seagate Momentus XT Hybrid ST750LX003 hard drive, and I was wondering if I should take any particular consideration in choosing the file-system type when installing Ubuntu 12.04?

From this answer, I take I should use `ext4`:
[configuration for Samsung SSD 830](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121676/configuration-for-samsung-ssd-830/124593#124593)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had one of these drives, you likely want plain ext4, these drives do all their magic at the hardware level so you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: Brilliant! Ordered!