# Installing Ubuntu on a new solid state drive

Tags: installation, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

I dropped my laptop and my hard disk is corrupted. I had dual boot win7 and Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 15R laptop. I have purchased a new Crucial 64 GB m4 2.5-Inch Solid State Drive. I want to install Ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04 on this hard drive. it will be a fresh install. I am planning to put this SSD in my laptop and then install Ubuntu. So my questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. Is there anything that I need to take care of at the time of installation?
3. How Ubuntu performs on SSD?

If installed Ubuntu will be my only OS on my laptop.