# Still need discard, noatime, and data=ordered for SSDs?

Tags: 12.10, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)

It's just been a while. Didn't know if SSDs are auto-detected, or if it's still necessary to use the discard, noatime, and data=ordered mount options.

Comment: Not much has changed in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I see no evidence that 12.10 auto-detects and installs accordingly with a SSD. I just did a fresh install and went ahead and added `discard` and `noatime` as well as moving `tmpfs` to the ram.

The articles I've used are a bit old, but they provide decent info/referencing on tweaking for SSDs:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1974320
http://cptl.org/wp/index.php/2010/03/30/tuning-solid-state-drives-in-linux/