# How to apply TRIM to an NTFS partition on an SSD drive?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs, ssd, trim

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7 installed in dual boot on a single SSD. In addition they share an NTFS partition where I put all my data and documents. How can I apply TRIM to this partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible.

The mount option *[discard](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#Ext4_code_implements_discard.2FTRIM)* is not available for [NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/) partitions.

Furthermore, the command *[fstrim](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html)* does not support NTFS, returns an error message if you try to trim an NTFS partition:

```
user@host:~$ fstrim -v /dos
fstrim: /dos: FITRIM ioctl failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```