# Does a fresh install of Ubuntu on an SSD need tweaking (to enable TRIM, etc.)?

Tags: ssd

I've heard that Ubuntu needs some tweaking for optimal performance when migrating an existing install to an SSD.

However, I have made a fresh install after switching to the SSD, so perhaps the installer has detected that it's an SSD and put the best defaults?

Or does it still need tweaking?

Comment: Yes, it still needs tweaking. (This is likely to change in 14.04) The only thing what the installer cares about is proper partition alignment, I think.  Please read [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/1400/221281).

Comment: Yes and do not use the discard method but fstrim (the discard method is slow).

Comment: [to tweak and optimize SSD for Ubuntu](http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html)