# I'm confused about SSD optimization

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I've tried to find out the deal with this, but I just can't. I have 3 drives in my rig. 1 240GB SSD, which I would like the main OS to go on (I have 16GB of RAM so no swap needed), a 1TB backup drive which will not be touched, and a 500GB drive for my `/home` and maybe `/var`. How can I optimize this to use TRIM for the SSD, set it up, etc?

Comment: possible dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/443761/how-is-trim-enabled-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how much information you need, so let me know if you need more technical information on how to "set it up".

Trim is default on Ubuntu 14.04, for Intel and Samsung SDDs. (Essentially, use a cron job, not discard.)

That's a massive SDD. My `/` partition is 25 GB, and is 15 GB full. If I were you, I'd put `/home` on the SDD too, so that things like your web browser and email client will work quickly. Then put your "extra" files (documents, music, pictures) on your 500 GB drive.

I also put some `/var` items on my spindle drive to reduce writes/wear on the SDD, although I've also read that this is unnecessary with newer SDDs. My spindle drive is mounted at `/HDD`, and I have the following in `/etc/fstab`.

```
/HDD/.SDDsymlinks/var/tmp /var/tmp none bind 0 0
/HDD/.SDDsymlinks/var/log /var/log none bind 0 0
/HDD/.SDDsymlinks/var/cache /var/cache none bind 0 0
```

I had some trouble with `/var/spool` so I didn't bother.