# Options for ssd mount point

Tags: ssd, mountpoint

I have to install Ubuntu on a SSD and I have to edit partitions manually at installation time. I know that Ubuntu is able to detect ssd hard disk with automatic partioning: if I choose partitiona manually have I to set particolar options for mount point?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What SSD optimization are needed on latest Ubuntu version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674320/what-ssd-optimization-are-needed-on-latest-ubuntu-version)

Comment: Yes, how can I set this question as duplicated?

Comment: I've voted to close as duplicate already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone hasn't answered, so I write the results of my search:

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd

[What SSD optimization are needed on latest Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674320/what-ssd-optimization-are-needed-on-latest-ubuntu-version)