# Ssd partitioning 120gb

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I have Lenovo M30-70
i3-4005U
4GB RAM
HD4400
120GB Patriot SSD
I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.1
How to partition my SSD(Swap,root...)?
Thanks

Comment: Will Ubuntu be the only OS on the drive? Your swap will be very fast on a SSD but will wear it out faster than normal if memory is actually swapped to disk (hopefully that won't happen very often with 4 GB ram).

Comment: Only Ubuntu on the drive

Comment: Swap wearing out an SSD faster is a myth nowadays, this really has not been the case for a long time.  If you have enough RAM, you basically won't swap at all, or only rarely.  And even if you do heavily swap all the time (the sign of a computer with too little RAM), modern SSDs can still take 10, maybe even 100 years of it without longevity ever becoming a problem.

Comment: Since you seem to have no other drives, there's no difference to other single-drive partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got a 128GB SanDisk USB Fit flash drive for the exact same purpose. I gave 3GB to swap and the rest went to root. Even though my laptop, comes with 8GB my ram usage is sitting at about 3GB right now but this is most likely because I'm running Google Chrome with several tabs open. I would definitely recommend a minimum of 2GB of swap for your setup though.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this question seems like a duplicate of [how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation). Please look at this question and accepted answer for the what you need to do.

Set your swap size to 4GB and hopefully it will be seldom used because swap on a SSD will wear it down faster.

After installation look at SSD life extending techniques such as TRIM and log file writes. In summary:

Add noatime,nodiratime to your ssd drives or partitions, after ext4

```
UUID=bef10b86-494d-41c6-aa46-af72cfba90fd / ext4 discard,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

UUID is your actual device not the one in the example. For more information read: [what-ssd-optimization-are-needed-on-latest-ubuntu-version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674320/what-ssd-optimization-are-needed-on-latest-ubuntu-version)

Don't worry about these technical details right away. You have lots of time to optimize your SSD life extension. We are talking of extending from 7 years to 10 years probably. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned any specific requirements that are out of the ordinary, so I would recommend going with the installer defaults.

The installer defaults are carefully chosen to be the best compromise that would satisfy the most situations.  The reason you alter defaults is when you have specific requirements, which you don't appear to have.

Comment: Geez I meant to put that in my answer too but was overly focused on the question. Well done.