# Can I use a Samsung 840 EVO with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ssd, samsung, trim

From some internet research, it looks like the [TRIM command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM_(SSD_command)) has bugs with the Samsung 8 series SSDs.
I don't know if this info is still current or if it was specific to 14.04. Can I use the 840 as my main drive with 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atleast for Ubuntu, Samsung and Intel SSDs are well supported, and automatic TRIM support is enabled by default. The current kernel version for Ubuntu 16.04 is 4.4 or higher, where optimizations for SSDs are already included within kernel, hence you do not need to worry.

From the user side, some additional optimizations maybe required which are easy to do. You can follow these link for details.

- question for [SSD optimization in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674320/what-ssd-optimization-are-needed-on-latest-ubuntu-version) ,
- question on [OS optimization for SSDs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- detailed [optimization for SSDs on debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization).

There is no reason for not using Samsung EVO series SSDs with Ubuntu.