# Ubuntu 16.04 & SSD

Tags: 16.04, ssd

I am considering swapping my HDD for a SSD, on which to install and run Ubuntu 16.04. Whereas a HDD seems to last for ever and one can check its health, I hear that SSDs have a short lifetime.

Is there a means on Ubuntu 16.04 of checking the health of SSDs?
Are there potential pitfalls to be aware of during Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Older article but advice still stands. https://askubuntu.com/questions/674320/what-ssd-optimization-are-needed-on-latest-ubuntu-version

Answer (score 1):

I had just recieved some bad sectors on my 500GB HDD, but my laptop also came with a 20GB SSD, so now temporairly I installed it on the SSD, and it works great, **no problems during the installation**. Also I don't know why you think that SSD have bad lifetime, they will be good for as long as you will be using it. Some things to consider are that SSD are still **kinda expensive** and i don't know how Ubuntu will **react to RAID Strips**, but I don't see why there should be a problem.

The **Disks application that comes preinstalled measures the health of your SSD** and HDD, and should tell you about any problems that it finds.

Comment: SSD life decreases with write operations, although its very slow even for heavy usage