# will ubuntu work with SSD

Tags: system-installation

I am planning to use a SSD in an old laptop Acer Aspire 4730Z  It has 4 gig ram.
and presently uses Vista.
I would like to replace the hard drive with a SSD and load only Ubuntu !

Any help ?  Or Suggestions ?

Comment: Why bother? What's the point of coupling an SSD with old hardware?

Comment: It may work. I've Radeon R7 128 GB SSD and it works alright with my Toshiba Satellite L455D laptop. But I somewhat agree with mikewhatever. Buying a newer laptop may be way more cost effective and useful in long term. But if you love that old laptop and don't want to part with it - sure, by all means try to install SSD there. Just make sure you [properly enable TRIM](http://askubuntu.com/a/443779/295286)

Comment: Two of my computers work perfectly with SSDs. I am confident yours will, too.

Comment: Does the Acer have AHCI mode for drives? Not just IDE nor RAID. Most newer systems have AHCI and that is required to correctly enable trim with a SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Of course SSD works with Ubuntu! How else do you think servers running Ubuntu Server run so fast? Now that's pretty much all the support you can get on this question and answer page without it being [off topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), so if you need help replacing, just look on YouTube or the Developers website. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine. Linux has drivers for most hardware, and a hard drive should be pretty standards compliant. The best way to make sure it will work is to just try it- just get yourself a [live USB or CD](http://www.pendrivelinux.com), and try installing to the hard drive. If the installer sees your hard drive, and installs the OS, then it works.