# How is trim enabled in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ssd, cron, fstab, trim

Does it work once a week or does it continually trim the system? 
I have seen answers for this but they refer to Ubuntu 14.04 but not to Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: there is weekly cron job but you need to enable no checking for device model. Ill link relevant post in a minute

Comment: [Here it is](http://askubuntu.com/a/443779/295286)

Comment: That was for Ubuntu 14.04. For Ubuntu 15.04 there is no model check needed or necessary. It just does not say though how often the check is done.

Comment: For Ubuntu 15.04 this is the output of the cron file. #!/bin/sh
# trim all mounted file systems which support it
/sbin/fstrim --all || true

Comment: @ErvinDine if it's a cron file, by virtue of being a cron file, it's known how often it runs. Where exactly is it located?

Comment: @muru it is in weekly ;) and it is the same as in 14.04 and it is in 15.04. Though more models work out of the box.

Comment: @ErvinDine still a dupe.  The correct way is to add differnces for 15.04 to that answer ;) I myself have not seen any differences in usage between trim in 14.04 and 15.04

Answer (score 0):

fstrim has changed in Ubuntu 15.04 compared to previous version. `fstrim-all --no-model-check` is now called as `fstrim --all`. There is no more option to desiable model-check.

`/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` does now contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
# trim all mounted file systems which support it
/sbin/fstrim --all || true
```

So you don't need to change anything in Ubuntu 15.04 concerning TRIM

Comment: Ah, the change happened in the previous version (14.10), not in 15.04, as the dupe post says.