# Notebook with two hard disk (SSD and mechanical)

Tags: partitioning, ssd, trim

I have a Notebook with two hard disk (one SSD and other mechanical). How can I divide partition? I think swap could go on mechanical one.
Will Ubuntu see that one is SSD and other no? I know SSD has different bytes page size (4096) and that it needs trim. Will Ubuntu manage correctly both hard disk in the same system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I divide partition?

System on the SSD: that will make it boot quick. Personal files on the HDD. In the case of failure of the SSD you can buy a new one, re-install the OS and simply mount the HDD.

See `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` on how to easily change the directories in your `/home/$USER/` to the 2nd hard disk. Reserve a copy of this file on the HDD so you can copy it back to `/home/$USER/.config/`.

So ...

- SSD: format and mount as /
- HDD: format and mount as a partition
- change `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

> I think swap could go on mechanical one.

Or no swap at all. I myself do not use hibernate or suspend anymore. Booting within 10 seconds is quick enough for me (I commute, watch anime in a train).

> Will Ubuntu see that one is SSD and other no?

Depends on your actions. If you (possibly format and) mount the HDD during setup it will be shown. If you don't and leave it unallocated you will need to do some manual work after installation to make it show.

> I know SSD has different bytes page size (4096) and that it needs trim. Will Ubuntu manage correctly both hard disk in the same system?

That depends on the brand of the SSD; answer likely is yes though. Trim will always be installed and it will trim the disk if it is on the supported SSD list. Also see [How is Trim enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443761/how-is-trim-enabled) and [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim) for some tricks and on how to test it.