# Specify ubuntu parttion size

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have installed in several computers (windows 10) Ubuntu 16.04 using a boot USB.
Until now I have used the default settings for the partitions during installation.
That is, in the picture below I choose the first option (Install Ubuntu alongside Windows) and let Ubuntu do the job.

[image]

However I have a computer with 250 GB hard disk. 100 GB are used already so they remain 150 GB from which I want 30 GB for Ubuntu.

How can I do this? I guess through the last option in the picture (Something else) but still I cannot figure out the proper and safe way.

Comment: see these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: @oldfred If the hard disk is a SSD is there any difference?

Comment: @pomsky I will accept the duplicate nature of the question. I have just two questions. Is it better and safer to create a partition from Windows first? Will the Ubuntu boot USB recognize it automatically afterwards? The replies given in the suggested links hold true for a SSD disk as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds