# Setup in-memory cache for SSD on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssd, performance, memory-usage, cache

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my notebook with 128G SSD. I found articles about SSD-cache for HDD usage. Does any reason exist to setup in-memory cache for SSD? Will I have any performance bonus in this case? I don't use HDD at all.

If there are a reasons to setup in-memory cache for SSD - how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything special, as free RAM is used for caching by default.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: HP Omen 17 with 16Gb RAM

Comment: @AlexGusev If you want to reduce the number of writes on your ssd, you can consider using `tmpfs`. Please read the [detailed explanation here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds/1675#1675)