# Does Ubuntu 11.04 fully support TRIM?

Tags: 11.04, ssd, trim

Does Ubuntu 11.04 fully support TRIM? And what happens if it doesn't, will my SSD wear out?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Does Ubuntu have TRIM command for use with SSD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256/does-ubuntu-have-support-for-the-trim-command-for-use-with-ssd)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to enable it manually by adding the discard option to your /etc/fstab like so:

```
/dev/mapper/faldara-natty /               ext4    discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Also the purpose of TRIM is to prevent a decrease in write throughput of the drive after much use, not to prevent it from wearing out.  I have been using a drive for over a year without TRIM and have yet to suffer any performance loss, so IMHO, it is much ado about nothing.