# Does Ubuntu 14.04 support SSD TRIM on Software RAID?

Tags: ssd, raid, trim

I'm using the softwareraid (mdraid) RAID1 on 2 Intel SSD DC S3500 and I found there's a fstrim job on cron.weekly. Does it mean Ubuntu supports it?

I could not find any article saying that SSD mdraid and fstrim is supported for RAID1. And this bug on launchpad is confusing:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1276941

I tried to run fstrim manually and it works:

```
sudo fstrim -v /
/: somerandomnumber bytes were trimmed
```

No luck with the fstrim-all as used in the cron.weekly since there's no verbose option to run that command. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1303199

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256/does-ubuntu-have-support-for-the-trim-command-for-use-with-ssd?rq=1) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62760/does-ubuntu-11-04-fully-support-trim?rq=1) (this is for 11.04, but probably still applies).

Comment: Thanks, all search results show me about discard mount option while I'm aiming for fstrim instead of discard. :)

Comment: I'm not sure about the RAID part, but if you read the cron job, you'll see that fstrim only runs for Intel and Samsung SSDs. More info [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/443779/53508), too.

Comment: Hi Sparhawk, I also got this verbose when doing "fstrim -v /" "/: somerandomnumber bytes were trimmed". I guess the cron.weekly fstrim will do the job. how to check the cron fstrim log if it has been run before?

Comment: @chrone You [can't](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1303199)! (Also, please put `@Sparhawk` in your reply, otherwise I don't get notified.)

Comment: @Sparhawk oh okay, I'm new here, sorry. :D What do you mean by the you can't? Is it I can't see the verbose of fstrim-all or I can't see the fstrim log done by cron.weekly on my Intel SSD + mdraid RAID1?

Comment: @chrone No worries. Perhaps I wasn't explicit enough. There's a bug link in my comment about. The weekly cron job uses `fstrim-all`, which creates no output. So unless you change the cron job to use `fstrim` instead (manually specifying paths), there's no way to tell if it works correctly or not.